# Solo, own pool, monero, need help

Tags: mining

I have about 50 instances I want to use for mining monero solo. I was hoping to setup my own pool and connect them all to it, but most tools such as coiniumserv don't support solo mining.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

How about setting up your own stratum engine with [MiningCore](https://github.com/coinfoundry/miningcore) and connect everything you have to that?